# 95% CI output in the regression table using gtsummary

Tags: logistic-regression, confidence-interval, gtsummary

How could I divide the Confidence interval column into two,corresponding to the upper and lower limits in regression table that I formulated using tbl_regression(), with keeping 95% CI as header for the two columns

I couldn't find a specific function.
I want the output of the table to be as the attached table in the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfllq.jpg)

Comment: can you point to an example of what you want to see as the output? you want two columns with a merged header?

Comment: Yes, two columns of upper/lower limits with 95%CI header

Answer (score 0):

See example below to get the table you're after.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.1'

tbl <-
  lm(age ~ grade, trial) |>
  tbl_regression() |> 
  # hide the current one-column CI
  modify_column_hide(ci) |> 
  # unhide the LB and UB
  modify_column_unhide(c(conf.low, conf.high)) |> 
  # add header for LB and UB
  modify_header(conf.low = "**LB**", conf.high = "**UB**") |> 
  # add spanning header
  modify_spanning_header(c(conf.low, conf.high) ~ "**95% CI**")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-06-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>